# Landsat RGB visualization in rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I am trying to visualize Landsat surface reflectance satellite imagery using rasterio in python, but the colors aren't right. I have tried to duplicate the solution for Sentinel 2A presented [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306164/how-to-visualize-multiband-imagery-using-rasterio) using Landsat SR imagery, but it seems to be too "bright", even after normalizing 0-1. The Landsat SR values are between 1-65535, with valid values between 7273 - 43636. I am able to visualize the Sentinel and Landsat images as natural color RGBs in both R and ArcGIS pro, so there don't seem to be an issues with the rasters I am using.

Here is the code from the above [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306164/how-to-visualize-multiband-imagery-using-rasterio).

```
file = r"C:\Path\to\Landsat8_SR.tif"
def pct_clip(array,pct=[2,98]):
    array_min, array_max = np.nanpercentile(array,pct[0]), np.nanpercentile(array,pct[1])
    clip = (array - array_min) / (array_max - array_min)
    clip[clip>1]=1
    clip[clip<0]=0
    return clip

with rio.open(file) as src:
    with rio.open(
            'RGB_Temp.tif', 'w+',
            driver='GTiff',
            dtype= rio.float32,
            count=3,
            crs = src.crs,
            width=src.width,
            height=src.height,
            transform=src.transform,
        ) as dst:
        V = pct_clip(src.read(4))
        dst.write(V,1)
        V = pct_clip(src.read(3))
        dst.write(V,2)
        V = pct_clip(src.read(2))
        dst.write(V,3)
    
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
with rio.open("RGB_Temp.tif") as src2:
    show(src2.read(),transform=src2.transform,ax=ax)
```

I am running rasterio in ArcGIS Pro/ VSCode, but I have run the above code at a simple command line as well, with the same results.

Comment: Can you add a image about your problem?

Comment: Works well for me with some test Landsat data that doesn't include the nodata areas surrounding the scene. Can you add an example screenshot?